# Change font size globally with a shortcut

Tags: fonts

When I need to change the font size I evaluate the following region:

```
  (set-frame-font "JetBrains Mono-14")
```

This is far from optimal since it involves a lot of typing.

I'm looking for an interactive function that would ask me for the new font size and modify the numeric value passed to `set-frame-font`.

As a workaround I wrote the following function:

```
(defun change-font-size (new-size)
  "Change the font size to the given value"
  (interactive "sNew font size: ")
  (set-frame-font (concat (face-attribute 'default :family) "-" new-size)
                  )
  )

(bind-key "C-x f" #'change-font-size)
```

But I wonder if there's a better way of doing this.

The best solution for me would be to change the font size of emacs based in the monitor in which it is being displayed, but I could not find any satisfactory solution. I do not want to do busy waiting on my emacs, instead I'd like emacs listening to notifications of the windows manager. However I do not know whether this is possible.

*EDIT* using the suggestion in one of the answers I wrote this hook to resize the window based on the display emacs is in.

```lisp
(defun my/adjust-font-size-based-on-display ()
  (let ((display-width (nth 3 (assq 'geometry (frame-monitor-attributes))))
        )
    (change-font-size
     (cond ((<= display-width 1920) 18) ;; HD
           ((<= display-width 2560) 11) ;; UWHD
           ((<= display-width 4096) 14) ;; 4K
           )
     )
    )
  )

(add-hook 'window-size-change-functions (lambda (frame) (my/adjust-font-size-based-on-display)))
(add-hook 'focus-in-hook 'my/adjust-font-size-based-on-display)
```

Suggestions on how to improve the hook above are welcome!

Comment: The Emacs default ```C-x C-+``` and/or ```C-x C--``` for increase/decrease font size does not work?

Comment: No, they only change the size for the current buffer and not globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:height` attribute of a face is ten times the font size. You can directly set the height attribute:

```el
(defun change-font-size (new-size)
  "Change the font size to the given value"
  (interactive "nNew font size: ")
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height (* 10 new-size)))
```

Note that it needs a number, not a string, so I changed your interactive `s` to `n`.

For the second part, where you have it depend on monitor size,

```el
(defun my/check-monitor ()
 (change-font-size 
   (if (<= (display-pixel-width) 1440) 16 20)))
```

This will set the font size to 16 if the monitor width is up to 1440px and 20 if it's a wider monitor. You can extend this to include more logic depending on width and height.

I am not sure if emacs has any built in hooks to detect a monitor change, but if not, either find a way to send a command to emacs (e.g. run `emacsclient -e "(my/check-monitor)"` from a shell script), or have it check the monitor width occasionally in a timer, maybe with `run-with-idle-timer`.

Comment: That works much better! Thank you! And I didn't think about sending a command to emacs from the window manager. That sounds like a good alternative. I have to check whether gnome WM supports these kind of hooks.

Comment: Regarding the hook, it seems `focus-in-hook` is what I need. Now I only need to figure out how to get emacs to correctly report the size of the display it is in: `display-pixel-width` reports always the pixel width of the external monitor.

Comment: I edited my question with a hook that achieves the automagically resizing. Has some caveats, but works for me :)

Comment: Great! I think `(display-pixel-width (car (frame-list)))` will tell you the pixel width of the monitor emacs is on, but emacs could have a frame on each monitor, so that would end up being ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will appeal to you but what I do is use `text-scale-increase` and `text-scale-decrease`. Putting them in a hydra like this:

```el
(require 'hydra)

(defhydra hydra-zoom (global-map "<f2>")
  "zoom"
  ("g" text-scale-increase "in")
  ("l" text-scale-decrease "out"))
```

then allows me to increase it a couple of times by typing `<F2> g g ...`, repeating the `g` (`g` for `greater` but suit yourself :-) ).

Although this is not a global change, I generally find that I don't need to *change* the font size globally: I set the font (including its size) once and for all in my init file to whatever I need for most of my work and then just use the above to change the size of the font in a buffer e.g. when presenting my screen in a meeting to make it readable.